# Transfer domains without disrupting local email server

Tags: web-hosting, email, networking

Perhaps I am thinking about this wrong, but maybe some of you guys can help me on this one.

I have a client who currently has a domain from Network Solutions and is hosted via GoDaddy. Additionally, he has his email service with GoDaddy as well, but it seems to be forwarded to his local server at work. How can I transfer hosting accounts without disrupting email service (or at least temporarily)?

Some MX info via Godaddy:

```
A

@ Points to GoDaddy Host
main Points to client's home server
sw Points to client's home server


MX
@ Points to main.example.com
@ Points to smtp.secureserver
@ Points to mailstore1.secureserver
```

Answer (score 1):

Due to the forwarding of the email it is as simple as setting up a new forward on the new 'email hosting'. If you plan to use the home server without a forwarder then you need to use the full mx records of the home server and not the hosting package.

To avoid downtime change the TTL on the domain to 1 hour and wait 24 hours of that to take effect globally. Then make the changes, technically the old service will continue to forward while the settings take effect so downtime should minimal. As a extra step you should always do the final step of changing the records in the least busy period for your client (I.e Weekend, and Evening times as an example.

Comment: Thanks, does this also apply if I want to change email service?

Comment: Yep, just ensure that you set the TTL's to a low value and wait for the 24hours before you do the major changes.

Comment: Thanks again, are you available to talk via email for a few minutes? - Sorry to ask here.